# creating a zip file that contains an iOS app that uses facebook API --> when extracting, always getting "facebook.h is missing error"

Tags: xcode, facebook

I am trying to create a zip file that contains an iOS XCode project, that anyone with XCode will be able to unzip it , open the project, build and run it. 
this project uses facebook SDK, and It's included it in the project's zip.

the problem is that when I extract the zip and run, I always get "facebook.h is missing" complile error. if I remove the facebook framework and put it again (like in this answer: [How to make Xcode find file FacebookSDK.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849209/how-to-make-xcode-find-file-facebooksdk-h)) , It solves the problem, But I want to make it easy to the users that download my app's project so they wouldn't need to do that.

actually, I don't believe there's something wrong in the zipping process, I think it's something to do with the project's settings.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found for this was to close xcode before zipping.

Did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your project go to: **"Build Settings”**, then **“Search Paths"**. Look for **"Frameworks Search Paths"**.

Use

```
Frameworks search paths:$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

For this to work, your facebookSDK framework should be placed/copied in your project folder.