# PFFacebookUtils.h (1.7.1) imports non-existent FacebookSDK.h

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I've installed the Parse and Facebook iOS SDKs for my project in Xcode. My project is written in Swift so I have the following in my bridging header:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import <ParseCrashReporting/ParseCrashReporting.h>
#import <Intercom/Intercom.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

When I build the app, I get 2 errors:

1. error: 'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found
2. error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/ben/AppFolder/MyApp/Bridging-Header.h'

The bridging header is at the directory as shown, so it seems that is dependent on the first error. FacebookSDK.h is in an #import statement at the top of PFFacebookUtils.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/PFConstants.h>
#import <Parse/PFNullability.h>
#import <Parse/PFUser.h>
```

FacebookSDK.h does not exist in either the Parse iOS SDK 1.7.1 or the Facebook SDK (presumably 4.0.1) from [Facebook's Getting Started page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started), though I know that FacebookSDK.h was in previous versions.

I tried the approved answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849209/how-to-make-xcode-find-file-facebooksdk-h) without success. Do I need to add something to my bridging header? Should I change the import statement for FacebookSDK.h to reference a different file? Other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

use :

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

Make sure to add that V4

Comment: Thank you. That got rid of the error, though it exposed a more core bug with the SDKs explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459073/issue-using-fbsdk-in-swift-ios-application).

Comment: I have Parse 1.7.1 and Facebook 4.0.1 via Pods, but I get the `ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h file not found` error. Any ideas?

Comment: @EnekoAlonso Make sure you've included the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework in the Build Phases.