# More FacebookSDK/Facebook.h issues - file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-sdk-4.0, xcode-project

Alright, guys. I'm going freakin' crazy with this one.  It is utterly ridiculous that the FacebookSDK causes so many issues. I know there are a couple questions on here regarding this issue, but they all seem to be outdated.

I pulled my Xcode project onto a new computer, and can't build it because I get the "FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h" file not found error.  There are answers such as [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849209/how-to-make-xcode-find-file-facebooksdk-h), but I've followed the steps in every single answer and haven't found one that works.  I've just made a fresh pull from my working project from the original machine to the new one.  I'll take some screenshots showing my current settings for various fields mentioned in other answers, and maybe I Just have something wonky that is interfering.

Here are the contents of the SDK that I *just* downloaded
[image: Here are the contents of the SDK that I *just* downloaded]

Here are the contents of my Xcode project folder.  There isn't anything else Facebook in here.
[image: Here are the contents of my Xcode project folder. There isn't anything else Facebook in here.]

Here are the frameworks inside my Frameworks group and inside the Link Binary with Libraries section of Build Phases
[image: Here are the frameworks inside my Frameworks group and inside the Link Binary with Libraries section of Build Phases]

There are a couple frameworks that are red, and that's OK for now. They were not in the repo, and are instead referenced from Documents or Downloads, and they played nice when I moved the files over and linked them.  I just reset my repo to when I pulled it to make sure I didn't have anything from weird stuff I tried that prevents a proper solution from working.

Framework search paths. You can also see that my library search paths is empty. I labeled the stuff I wanted to hide, as it was identifying information
[image: Framework search paths. You can also see that my library search paths is empty. I labeled the stuff I wanted to hide, as it was identifying information]

For some reason, my Documents for the new machine is already under the framework search paths. I did not add this myself.

Any ideas on what I can try? This is endlessly frustrating.  I've wasted an entire day of development on trying to get Facebooks SDK re-integrated on a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was also face the same problem every time I got the checkout for new version from svn.What I did was just removed the Facebook SDK and add again from the backup.It taken me out that time.Please try this might be it works for you.